# (Revisited$_2$) Injectivity Relies on The Existence of an Onto Function Mapping Back to Its Preimage

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, axiom-of-choice, function-and-relation-composition

---

### QUEST:

> For any sets $X$ and $Y$, there exists an injective function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ if and only if there exists a surjective function $g:Y\rightarrow X$.

---

### QUESTION$_1$:

How do you people approach this problem. I mean, what is running through your brain when you look at each of the above statements?

---

### KNOWN:

> $\dagger\hspace{.5cm}$If $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is injective, then there exists a function $g: Y \rightarrow X$ such that $g \circ f = 1_X$.
>
> $\dagger\hspace{.5cm}$If $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is surjective, then there must exist a function $g:Y \rightarrow X$ such that $f \circ g = 1_Y$.

---

### THOUGHTS:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder_theorem

---

### ATTEMPT$_{Q1}$: $\leftarrow$ This attempt is wrong, just so you know...

Since $f$ is an injection it is a bijection onto its image, and so there exists an inverse $h:f(X)\rightarrow X$. Now, let $x$ be an arbitrary element in $X$, and define $g:Y\rightarrow X$ by
$$g(y) =
\begin{cases}
h(y), & \text{if }y\in f(X) \\
x, & \text{otherwise }
\end{cases},$$
so $g$ is a bijection and therefore a surjection.

---

### QUESTION$_2$:

Let $\precsim$ be a relation defined by
$$X\precsim Y~\iff~\exists~f:X\rightarrow Y~(1-1).$$

Let $\succsim$ be a relation defined by
$$X\succsim Y~\iff~\exists~f:X\rightarrow Y~(\text{onto}).$$

How are $\precsim$ and $\succsim$ related in the context of QUEST's proof?

---

### ATTEMPT$_{Q2}$: $\leftarrow$ Maybe somebody will check this...

By the Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem, if $X\precsim Y$ and $Y\succsim X$, then $X\cong Y$, so we can define a relation $\leq$ on cardinalities as follows:
$$\lvert X \rvert \leq \lvert Y \rvert~~~\text{if}~~~X\precsim Y,$$
namely $\exists~f~\text{s.t.}~f:X\rightarrow Y~(1-1)$, which suggests that $\leq$ is anti-symmetric since
$$\lvert X \rvert \leq \lvert Y \rvert~\text{and}~\lvert Y \rvert \leq \lvert X \rvert \iff X\precsim Y~\text{and}~Y\precsim X,$$
if and only if there exists injective maps $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow X$, so there exists also an injective map $h:X\rightarrow Y$, by C-B-S, and so $X\cong Y\iff \lvert X \rvert = \lvert Y \rvert$, where $\lvert * \rvert$ denotes cardinality.

Comment: In my head I just think **size**. It has to be true.

Comment: The words left-inverse and right-inverse dance through my mind until they collide with $f$ and $g$. And then in the debris I'm reminded of the Axiom of Choice. Btw, what do you mean with "each of the above" statements when I count only one statement above?

Comment: "***Warning: Axiom of Choice may be necessary***" (this is just what runs through my head looking at this problem, I don't know if it actually is or not)

Comment: "if": choice function for $g^{-1}(\{x\})$, "only if" - well, $X = \varnothing \neq Y$ provides a counterexample. But if we exclude empty sets, choose any $x \in X$ and extend $f^{-1}$ to all of $Y$.

Comment: Sort of a collection of cones with apexes the elements of $X$ and bases are subsets in $Y$ covering $Y$.

Comment: @DanielFischer What do you mean by "...and extend $f^{-1}$ to all of $Y$"?

Comment: Since $f$ is injective, $f^{-1}$ is a function with domain $f(X) \subset Y$. Extend that to all of $Y$ by setting $g(y) = x$ for $y \in Y\setminus f(X)$.

Comment: You are talking about Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem, yes?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I mean linguistically each "proposition" contained in my "statement."

Comment: How about using two **different** symbols for the two relations, rather than the same symbol in reverse? Standard notations are $X\leq Y$ if there is an injection from $X$ into $Y$, and $X\leq^\ast Y$ if there is a surjection from $Y$ onto $X$, or if $X=\varnothing$.

Comment: My textbook uses these.

Comment: @Trancot: If you assume the axiom of choice, then it's fine. But if you are set to try and prove something and you ask on the role of the axiom of choice in the process, then at least trying to pretend that you don't already assume the question is true is a sign of good faith.

Comment: What are you saying?

Comment: @Trancot: I'm saying that in mathematics, when we define a relation, say $X\sqsubset Y$, then we implicitly assume that whenever we write $X\sqsupset Y$ we actually mean $Y\sqsubset X$. So if you plan on asking whether or not the existence of an injection is equivalent to the existence of a surjection in the reverse direction, it would be nice not using $\precsim$ and $\succsim$ for the relations *until after you have proved that claim*.

Comment: Oh, OK. Thank you for the note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have all the ingredients in your question.

If there is an injective function $f\colon X\to Y$, then your fact 1 gives you a function $g\colon Y\to X$; is it what you're looking for?

If there is a surjective function $g\colon Y\to X$, then your fact 2 gives you a function $f\colon X\to Y$ such that $g\circ f=1_X$ (just reverse the role of $f$ and $g$ and of $X$ and $Y$); is it what you're looking for?

---

Complete solution. I accept your two facts as known, but stated in a slightly different way:

1. Every injective function has a left inverse
2. Every surjective function has a right inverse

Suppose there exists an injective function $f\colon X\to Y$. By fact 1, $f$ has a left inverse, that is, a function $g\colon Y\to X$ such that $g\circ f=1_X$. I claim that the function $g$ is surjective; indeed, if $x\in X$, we have
$$
x = g\circ f(x) = g(f(x)) = g(y)
$$
where $y=f(x)$.

Suppose conversely that there exists a surjective function $g\colon Y\to X$. By fact 2, $g$ has a right inverse, that is, a function $f\colon X\to Y$ such that $g\circ f=1_X$. I claim that the function $f$ is injective; indeed, if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then
$$
x_1=g\circ f(x_1) = g(f(x_1))=g(f(x_2))=g\circ f(x_2)=x_2.
$$

Comment: What do you mean reverse the role?

Comment: @BarisaBarukh You can write fact 2 as "if $g\colon Y\to X$ is surjective, then there exists $f\colon X\to Y$ such  that $g\circ f=1_X$". Sorry, I had the wrong order in the answer.

Comment: I don't see how this all fits together.

Comment: These relations are related by implication, right? (SEE EDIT)

Answer (score 0):

Am I the only one who sees a mistake here?

Quote:
"By the Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem, if $X\precsim Y$ and $Y\succsim X$, then $X\cong Y$, so we can define a relation $\leq$ on cardinalities as follows:"

That's not the Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder theorem. This is the CBS theorem:
If $X\precsim Y$ and $Y\precsim X$, then $X\cong Y$
where the original poster defined $X\precsim Y$ as there exists an injective function from X to Y.